# Get Json specific variable data from Coinmarketcap API

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting up a google sheet script to get coin prices from coinmarketcap API. With Json I'm able to get the coin price but when the coin URL change the script gives an error.

```
function getCryptoPrice(coin) {

  var url="https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=" + coin;

  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MY-API-KEY'
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};

  var httpRequest= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var getContext= httpRequest.getContentText();

  var parseData=JSON.parse(getContext);

  return parseData.data.GVT.quote.USD.price;
}
```

When "coin" changes the URL change too but "`return parseData.data.GVT"...`" still get the same coin symbol "GVT". How can I edit

`return parseData.data.GVT.quote.USD.price`

to get the coin price when the symbol GVT change?

Json parse text:

```
{data={GVT={symbol=GVT, circulating_supply=4426883.31189056, last_updated=2019-06-04T14:49:03.000Z, total_supply=4436643.92853333, cmc_rank=260, platform={symbol=ETH, name=Ethereum, token_address=0x103c3a209da59d3e7c4a89307e66521e081cfdf0, id=1027, slug=ethereum}, tags=[], date_added=2017-11-15T00:00:00.000Z, quote={USD={percent_change_1h=-0.00743386, last_updated=2019-06-04T14:49:03.000Z, percent_change_24h=-4.46141, market_cap=1.494379345295687E7, price=3.37569174521, volume_24h=1445068.31606641, percent_change_7d=-3.74407}}, num_market_pairs=17, name=Genesis Vision, max_supply=null, id=2181, slug=genesis-vision}}, status={error_message=null, elapsed=45, credit_count=1, error_code=0, timestamp=2019-06-04T14:49:56.313Z}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bracket notation to access the data:

```
parseData.data[coin].quote.USD.price;
```

Comment: @Ali Great! FWIW, I don't think any of the requestOptions is working (except headers), because none of them are accepted as a  argument in urlfetch. You probably should enclose them within `payload`. Review urlfetchapp documentation.

Comment: I see. I just copy/pasted them from coinmarketcap API documentation ( https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide ), thanks for the clarification! You are great. :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier if you simply did

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/ETH")`