# How to get object value from this Json

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have response from Json, I try a lot of method to get value but don't give me what I need.

this is the code:

```
function test() {

   var url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=BTCUSD';

   var apiRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   var jsonResponce = JSON.parse(apiRequest);
   Logger.log(jsonResponce);
   var price = jsonResponce.result.XXBTZUSD.a; // test if can I get value from array
   Logger.log(price) // It's work here
   var fine = price.map(obj => [obj[0]]); // Now test to get value from inside array
   Logger.log(fine) // but give just first character in number
 }
```

This is result :

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? The result is logical, with `obj[0]`, you are asking for first character.

Comment: [This is also the second time this question has been asked in the last two days.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69599716/get-value-from-json-return-return-api). Nothing has changed except the way you access the data.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @Andy so, I know this is the first method I use. Give me the solution if you have...

Comment: Add the expected output to your question. What are you looking for?

Comment: I want to find first number in array a `a=[60821.90000, 1, 1.000]` first number is `60821.90000`

Comment: just `price[0]`

Comment: @TheMaster thanks it's work. and change in this line is work: `var price = jsonResponce.result.XXBTZUSD.a[0];` but take a lot of time to get result not ass fist method I use. so can I get same result but without add `XXBTZUSD` in this line: `var price = jsonResponce.result.XXBTZUSD.a;` ?

Comment: No. It should make zero difference in speed. If something is slow, it's not due to this. In any case I suggest that you [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#array_object) before making any more code.

Comment: @ThaMaster in this array the name `XXBTZUSD` in dynamic I try to get this name from array but return me `null` I do this code: `var newarray = jsonResponce.result;` . the array start like that `{XXBTZUSD={a=[60868.60000, 1]}}` , then I do `var newSymbol= newSymbol[0]` to get this name `XXBTZUSD` but return `null`

Comment: @ThaMaster I do this code to get name array: `for (var key in lastArray) {
    var nameArray = key;} Logger.log(nameArray)` work fine but after I put this result in `var price = jsonResponce.result.nameArray;` give me null , Don't able to find array.

Comment: `jsonResponce.result[nameArray]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448428/  Kindly ask follow up questions as  new questions. Also, spending time to learn the basics would help you a lot in actually saving time.